# AppCenter is not updating the system

Tags: appcenter

[image: Screenshot]

It looks exactly same as you see in the picture above. I was be able to click to install before, but I can't click it anymore. It says "No components with updates".

This may have happened because of me, I closed the AppCenter during the download process.

Comment: I have the same problem:
App Center shows me that an update is available for three components. When I click on "Update", it says: "Load buffer" and after a short "Start". Then the state is as before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably up to date, closing AppCenter while it's downloading an update probably didn't stop it, it likely finished in the background.

If you want to double check, you can ensure your system is up to date the "old way" via a couple of terminal commands...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

elementary is ramping up for a new version, so in all likelihood, they are telling developers to hold off on the upgrades. Meanwhile the Ubuntu LTS it is based on is also getting long in the tooth. You'd need to activate a backports repo to get new upgrades.

Just wait for eOS Juno to come out. You will have enough to cope with then.

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly different problem; AppCenter is notifying me that there are updates, and when I click on AppCenter/Installed, it shows me the updates. However, when I click on "Update all" and enter my password, in less than a second I see in this order; "Loading cache", "Finished", "Starting" and it stops, not having updated anything, still showing the same updates.
[image]

However, when I do

> sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get upgrade
>   it seems to work, but after that AppCenter still shows the same updates and still behaves the same. I don't know what is going on, perhaps AppCenter cache needs to be cleared, but I don't know how.

I can install other apps (I installed a simple card game successfully)

I have elementary OS 5.1 Hera, Built on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, Linux 4.15.0-74- generic, GTK 3.22.30 on an HP EliteBook-840-G3 laptop.

Everything else seems to work fine.
What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Would you please report this issue to eOS devs @ https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues ?

Answer (score 0):

Für 3 Komponenten sind Updates verfügbar:
• libowncloudsync0 the ownCloud sync library Version: 2.7.3+oc-2877
• owncloud-client-doc development files for the ownCloud sync lib Version: 2.7.3+oc-2877
• owncloud-client-l10n Internationalization files for ownCloud Version: 2.7.3+oc-2877